# Create KeyValuePair instance with dynamic type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection

I'm looking way to Create KeyValuePair instance and setting key & Value dynamically using reflection.

This is part of

```
 foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
```

loop which iterates through properties and tries to recover them according to some conditions. KeyValue Pair is seems to be complicated.

I have these two type definitions

```
var keyType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
var valueType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[1];
```

Here I can create an Instance of my KeyValuePair..

```
var keyValuePair = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
```

But the key and the value are read only properties from outside and could be set only by constructor.

Any Ideas ??

Comment: Use reflection to get the correct ConstructorInfo with key and value parameters, and use that to call the constructor.

Comment: What type of key in your KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 3):

Call the constructor with the values for Key and Value:

```
var keyValuePair = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, new [] {key, val});
```